# How can I add a "snooze" button in Django with Ajax?

Tags: django, ajax

In my Django app I want to have a snooze button, which I want to use in order to postpone a deadline for an object. The corresponding model has a datefield called alarm and I want to pass the snooze command together with a number x of days that should be added to the current setting. So far I found out that I cannot do this directly from the template and multiple sites suggested the use of Ajax. I have never used that.

My files look like this.
**views.py**

```
def Operation_Snooze_Method(request):
    print(request)
    if request.POST:
        if request.is_ajax():
            print("Ajax")
            # I guess here I would handle the alarm if I could bring the Ajax call to work at all.
        else:
            print("no ajax")
        print(request.POST)
    return render(request, templ_folder_name + landingpage)
```

part of my **models.py**

```
class Operation(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name="Title of the operation")
    alarm = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date of the alarm", null=True, blank=True)
    [...]
    def Operation_Snooze(self,x):
        self.alarm = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=x)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('snooze/', views.Vorgang_Snooze_Method, name="snooze"),
```

my **base.html**, which is the template that I extend with my other templates

```
    $document.ready(function(){
        $("#snooze").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"{% url 'app_name_myproject:snooze' %}",
                data:{
                    'id':$('#snooze').val()
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
                },
            });
            return false;
        };)
    });
</script>

[...]
 {% if urgent_operations %} # this is a list of operations, just strings as a list
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-9 col-md-offset-2 main">
                    <div style="border:solid; border-color:red; padding:10px;">
                        <strong>Urgent operations:</strong><br>
                        <table>
                        {% for uo in urgent_operations %}
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-right:30px;">{{dv}}<td>
                                <td><form method="post" id="snooze" action="">{%csrf_token%}<button class="btn btn-block btn-default" name="id" value="13" type="submit">Snooze for 7 days</button></form></td> # the 13 has no meaning. Later I want to add the id of the corresponding object, but this is just for testing purposes.
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
```

As I am not done with everything, it is clear that the snooze function cannot work, but I even have a problem with the Ajax part and I have to find out why at first. When I click the button the entire landing page reloads. I thought with Ajax it is somehow possible only to reload a part of the page or to trigger a function on the server. Therefore, I would like to come to a point where I just click the button and the alarm snooze function is triggered. And if possible then I would only reload that part of the template where I check whether there are urgent operations coming up.

PS: I hope my English is okay. Perhaps operations is a misleading translation. It is about tasks or whatever you want to call them.

Comment: `id="snooze"` you are setting this on your form tags inside a loop. An id is meant to be unique, so when you attach an event using `$("#snooze").submit(...)` The selector returns only the first matching element it finds and you attach an event to only that element. So when you try to submit the other forms they actually get submitted as your event is not attached to their submission.

Comment: Dear Abdul
Thanks for the fast reply. You are right. But right now and for testing purposes I only have one operation in the database. So I have to deal with this soon, too.

Comment: Hi, you will error inside browser console and  `$document` should be `$(document)`

Comment: Dear Swati,
I have changed to $(document), but still I do not see anything happen. What else could I miss? I guess a lot, as I am a total js rookie.

Comment: @MDoe check browser console is there any error showing .

Comment: @MDoe simply when one has multiple of similar things what does one to in HTML to have similar css for them? They use a class, similarly you should assign a class to all of your form tags let's say `class="snooze"` now your selector would become `$(".snooze")` so you would attach event on the forms submit as `$(".snooze").submit(...)`

Comment: Dear Swati
I tried that, but I have no experience there. When I go in the firefox to Tools -> Tools -> Browser Console, a new window opens. But when I then go back to the main window of firefox it does not respond to anything until I close that console window again :(

Comment: @Swati: I tried the Web Console instead and perhaps I found something. It says:
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
The line
$(document).ready(function(){
is highlighted
Do I have to do that in a particular way?

Comment: Short Update: I found via google that this might be due to placing it before the jquery import. Will try that and write back later,

Comment: I found even more errors. Like $ajax instead of $.ajax. I have to work on this and then I will return to this thread later.

Comment: I am so happy. I got it working, at least to that extent that I can change the object's properties. And can you also give me advice, how to update the website so that the div with the operation and the snooze button is no longer shown?

Comment: @MDoe please elaborate more .

Comment: @Swati: Thank you. I solved it with .toggle().